# Why aren't my :style() overwrites surviving page-reload?

Tags: firefox, ublock-origin, ublock

Once the extraneous (and useless) `div`s and `span`s are removed from a typical news-article, the actual text often remains in a narrow column surrounded by swaths of white-space reserved for the removed elements.

I've been trying to overwrite the CSS parameters on the sites I frequent to allow the surviving elements to use the wide areas left by the removed ones.

Figuring out, what style to change may be a challenge on its own, but even after you find the right settings and the text expands nicely, *it does not stick*  -- reloading the same page resets everything back.

For example, here are my settings for NYTimes.com:

```
www.nytimes.com##.StoryBodyCompanionColumn > [class^=css]:nth-child(n + 2)
www.nytimes.com##.StoryBodyCompanionColumn > *:style(max-width: none; width: 99%)
```

The first rule always works -- removing the second column from any article. The second rule seeks to resize surviving, main, column. And it works too, when I *first* enter it.

But reloading the page breaks it all -- even though the rule is properly saved.

What's happening and how to deal with it?